# Ember acceptance test multiple keypress event

Tags: jquery, ember.js, ember-cli, acceptance-testing, ember-testing

I want to simulate multiple keypress(ctrl+alt, alt+enter, alt+uparrow etc) events for my acceptance test cases.

[Ember test documentation](https://www.emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Test.html#method_triggerEvent) has given an abstract syntax for the triggerEvent method. It's still unclear how to use it for multiple keypress events simulation.

edit: adding the code after the suggestion from comments.

> let keytrigger = testSelector('random-id', "1");
>
> triggerEvent(keytrigger, "keypress",{17,38});

Please help!

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share some code. We need to see what you have tried so far. :)

Comment: Sure.
```var keytrigger  = testSelector('random-id', "1");
triggerEvent(keytrigger, "keypress",{17,38});
```
Also, I looked into [keyEvent](https://www.emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Test.html#method_keyEvent) which in turn calls [triggerEvent](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v2.12.0/packages/ember-testing/lib/helpers/key_event.js#L5) 

Need help on how to get my task done.

Comment: I suggest you to put the code in your question. You can edit it. ;)

Comment: @KarthikeyanMalaisamy did not the answer I had provided work for you?

Comment: that is great, good luck!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It must be something like

```
triggerEvent('.myInputElement', 'keydown', {
  keyCode: 38,   // up arrow
  altKey: true,
  ctrlKey: true

});
```

for simulating ctrl+alt+up arrow simultaneously. For other properties to pass to keyboard event you can take a look at [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) I guess.

Comment: Should not it be a sequence of `keyboardEvent`s like `keydown` followed by `keyup`.

Comment: I am trying to do a  CTRL+G with `triggerEvent(node, 'keydown', {keyCode: 71, ctrlKey: true});` but still it does not work. is there any other method to do that.

Comment: If you don't know the answer, why are you responding? If your response starts with "It must be something like" and ends with "I guess," you've done something wrong.